# jquery loop through li create json process it in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

I have list of items in database

```
ITEMS
  I_id int,
  I_name varchar(50),
  I_order int
```

I displayed it in ul li

```
<ul id='items'>
   <li><span class='txt'>item-1</span> <span class='mOrder'>1</span></li>
   <li><span class='txt'>item-2</span> <span class='mOrder'>2</span></li>
   <li><span class='txt'>item-3</span> <span class='mOrder'>3</span></li>
   <li><span class='txt'>item-4</span> <span class='mOrder'>4</span></li>
   <li><span class='txt'>item-5</span> <span class='mOrder'>5</span></li>
   <li><span class='txt'>item-6</span> <span class='mOrder'>6</span></li>
   <li><span class='txt'>item-7</span> <span class='mOrder'>7</span></li>
   <li><span class='txt'>item-8</span> <span class='mOrder'>8</span></li>
   <li><span class='txt'>item-9</span> <span class='mOrder'>9</span></li>
</ul>
<input type='button' id='btnSave' value=' Save order ' />
```

sorted through jquery sortable plugin

```
$(".items").sortable({
   $(".items li").each(function () {
       var OrderNum = (parseInt($(this).index()) + 1);
       $(".mOrder", this).html(OrderNum);
   });
});
```

now I want to save new order
I have saveOrder.ashx file to update records in database
I have problem while sending data in ajax
I am trying as below

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(){
    var arr=[];
    $(".items li").each(function () {
        arr.push({'m'+$(this).index():$(".txt",this).html()});
        //m0:item1, m1:item2,....
    });
    $.ajax({
         url:'',
         data:arr;//here is problem
    });
});
```

I am sending this but it is not accessable in saveOrder.ashx
I can try any alternative

Comment: Post the code for `saveOrder.ashx`

Answer (score 0):

I may have 2 answers:

1. wrap the array in a JSON object:

   url:'',
   data: {'arrayofObjects':arr}
2. JSON.stringify()

   url:'',
   data: JSON.stringify(arr)

ADDITIONAL:

1. JSON.stringify() + JSON object wrap

   url:'',
   data: JSON.stringify({arrayofObjects:arr})